# How does the 555-timer AM radio work?

Tags: timer, radio, 555, amplitude-modulation

The 555-timer is used here as a demodulator. I don't understand how the 555-timer generates the desired signal. Shouldn't the output have the same frequency as the carrier signal? Can someone please explain to me how the 555-timer is used here? I am new in this area and therefore do not have so much experience and knowledge.

Here is the link to the AM radio circuit:
http://tubetime.us/index.php/2011/02/23/555-contest-entry/
[image]

For example, how does the 555 timer convert the AM signal into an information signal?
[image]

Comment: replace the 555 block with its internal schematic

Comment: it's a **Very** nonstandard way of using the 555. The article you link to explains in some detail how it works. Could you elaborate on your questions based on that article? No, it should *not* have the same frequency as the carrier signal. This isn't a mixer, it's an envelope demodulator, and a hard-to-mathematically-describe one at that.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the 555 timer outputs the desired frequency. With 2/3 of the supply voltage at the input, the 555 timer outputs low. And since the carrier signal reaches the 2/3 Vcc at a certain frequency, the NE555 should output low at the same frequency. At least that is my understanding of how the 555-timer works.

Comment: It does NOT use an old 555 IC. instead it uses a modern Cmos 555 that has a much higher input resistance. The audio from the radio in the video sounds awful and is probably only the powerful nearby station.